# Submitting array to database

Tags: php

I am having some issues with submitting an array of inputs to the database.

More specifically I am getting this error "Array to string conversion" on the line where I bind the parameters. How would I submit the array through the foreach loop so that they are all individual of each other.

Here is the form

```
<form name = "entries" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="myInputs[]">
<input id = "submit1" name="submit1" type="submit">
```

and here is the php

```
    $inputs = (empty($_POST['myInputs'])) ? : $_POST['myInputs'] ;
    foreach ((array)$inputs as $eachInput) {
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `entries` (entries) VALUES(:inputs)");
        $query->bindParam(':inputs', $inputs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to replace your PHP code with below code.

```
$inputs = $_POST['myInputs'];
if(count($inputs) > 0) {
    foreach ($inputs as $eachInput) {
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `entries` (entries) VALUES(:inputs)");
        $query->bindParam(':inputs', $eachInput, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

If any query then let me know.

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome. Why did I have to change it from     $inputs = (empty($_POST['myInputs'])) ? : $_POST['myInputs'] ; to $inputs = $_POST['myInputs']; though? thats the only part I don't understand

Comment: @user3594895 I just make it in proper way. If you got blank array then doesn't need to run foreach loop. your code is also right :)